# Gluing $n$-homotopy equivalences

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

Let $f:X \rightarrow Y$ be a map between simplicial complexes.  Let $C$ and $C'$ be subcomplexes of $Y$ such that $Y = C \cup C'$.  Define $D = f^{-1}(C)$ and $D'=f^{-1}(C')$, so $D \cap D' = f^{-1}(C \cap C')$.  For some $n \geq 0$, assume that $f$ restricts to $n$-homotopy equivalences $D \rightarrow C$ and $D' \rightarrow C'$ and $D \cap D' \rightarrow C \cap C'$.  Question: must $f$ be an $n$-homotopy equivalence?  I assume that the answer is "yes", but it would be great to have a citable reference.

Using Mayer-Vietoris, one can show that $f$ induces isomorphisms on homology up to degree $n$.  Moreover, using Seifert-van Kampen, one can show that $f$ induces an isomorphism on $\pi_1$ if $n \geq 1$.  So the result is true if either $X$ or $Y$ is simply-connected.

Comment: Can't you use Mayer-Vietoris with local coefficients to conclude in the general case?

Comment: @DenisNardin: Do you know a reference for that (including the relevant version of the Whitehead theorem)?  I can't find it in Hatcher.

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/124278/mayer-vietoris-sequence-in-homology-with-local-coefficients

Comment: For the Whitehead theorem with local coefficients I don't remember a reference off the top of my head and I'm away from books, but it's pretty much a formal consequence of obstruction theory. Maybe in the book by Mosher and Tangora?